# Python: define class object that is list of the other methods in the class

Tags: python, class

I have the following class:

```
class Math():

    def double(self, x):
        return 2*x

    def triple(self, x):
        return 3*x
```

Now, I want to get the list of methods defined in the class. I can do this in the following way:

```
method_list = [func for func in dir(Math) if callable(getattr(Math, func)) and not func.startswith("__")]
```

Now, I would like `method_list` itself to be an object of the class Math. It doesn't work to simply define it (as it is now at least) inside the class. How can I do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. What **exactly** is it that you are looking for? "Now, I would like method_list itself to be an object of the class Math." is vague, what do you mean?

Comment: You might be able to get a decorator to do this.

Comment: IIUC, you can just do `Math.method_list = [<your list comprehension>]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
class Math():

    def double(self, x):
        return 2*x

    def triple(self, x):
        return 3*x

    @classmethod 
    def method_list(cls):
       return [func for func in dir(cls) if callable(getattr(cls, func)) and not func.startswith("__") and func != "method_list"]
```

usage example at interactive session:

```py
In [123]: Math.method_list()                                                                                                                                        
Out[123]: ['double', 'triple']
```

Comment: Thanks @jsbueno! But, 1) shouldn't method_list have a self argument? and 2) this includes method_list in the output, which I don't want. It is possible to fix this by  adding `and not  func.startswith("method_list")` in the list comprehension, but not sure whether this is the most elegant way of doing it.

Comment: It does not need the  `self` argument - it is marked as a  `classmethod`  and receives the class itself instead of an instance. By convention, we call the argument `cls` instead of `self`. As for supressing itself from the generated list, yes, including an extra condition in the filter condition is a practical way to go, but we can use `==` instead of `.startswith`. I will update the code to do that.

Comment: I can't make it work without adding the self argument. I am using Python 3.7.6. Could you perhaps provide an example, where you generate the desired list?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a decorator because the class must be fully defined for python to pass the class to the decorator.

```
def addMethods(cls):
    method_list = [func for func in dir(cls) if callable(getattr(cls, func)) and not func.startswith("__")]
    cls.method_list = method_list
    return cls

@addMethods
class Math():
    pass
```

Comment: You don't really need a decorator, just `Math.method_list = [<list comprehension using Math>]`

Comment: Although this decorator is a generalisation.